# I have a book written in Word format

Tags: conversion

There seems to be answers on here for converting `.docx` books to read on the kindle, but what would I have to do to allow it to be read on more platforms then the kindle? A lot of people I know do not have kindles and will an IPad for example read kindle formatted ebooks?

Comment: Why the downvote? While this is obvious to anyone with knowledge of ebook formats, it's not inherently obvious that the various formats are easily-convertible (especially with DRM muddying the waters).

Comment: Thankyou @evilsoup for the support, I did not indeed know and although happy with the answer, I did not see when looking at that question and answer prior to placing mine. I thought the idea was that this area was meant to helpful and not to be jumped on from great heights when making a mistake. Oh well will remember for next time.

Comment: Try not to take it personally -- the idea is that we vote on questions/answers rather than people. Still, I don't see what's wrong with this question (but then, I'm not a regular here).

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer for the question [How do I convert a Word document into an ebook?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/a/11/60) describes how to convert a book in `.docx` format to AZW3.

As is very clear from the 3rd picture in that answer, where AZW3 is selected as output format, that there is a whole list of "calibre output formats". Searching the latter phrase should get you to the complete list of supported formats in the FAQ: 
[AZW3, EPUB, FB2, OEB, LIT, LRF, MOBI, HTMLZ, PDB, PML, RB, PDF, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#what-formats-does-app-support-conversion-to-from).

From that list, someone can just select what they prefer for their device and/or software¹. For iPad users that depends on their software, but if that doesn't support AZW3 directly, it probably does support EPUB.

Assuming you already can convert the `.docx` to AZW3, and since the capabilities of EPUB and AZW3 in formatting the eBook are very similar, selecting the conversion is the only thing you (or the owner of the iPad) needs to do. There is not going to be any *additional* considerations, beyond what you do for going from `.docx` to AZW3, on how to go about the conversion².

¹ <sub>One can argue that if the device/software does not support any of these formats, it should not be called an eBook reader.</sub>
² <sub>That should only be an a concern if the other output format allows for very little formatting control, like TXT</sub>

Answer (score 2):

An iPad will read a Kindle formatted book if that iPad has the free [Kindle app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kindle/id405399194?mt=12) installed. You can also convert the book to epub format, which is readable by the other major reading systems like Nook, Kobo, Google Play, and iBooks. How to go about that conversion will depend on the specifics of your manuscript and how comfortable you are with coding—for a straight text manuscript, like a novel, conversion is fairly straightforward and there are tools available to help with it. For highly designed works like cookbooks or children's books, things get a bit more hands-on with the code.